# Unable to reinstall Nagios

Tags: linux, nagios, apt

I installed nagios messed up the configuration and uninstalled it. Now I am trying to reinstall but I get errors and cant install.

```
jason@jason-VirtualBox:/etc$ sudo apt-get install nagios3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nagios3 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 264 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up nagios3-common (3.2.3-1ubuntu1.2) ...
chown: cannot access `/etc/nagios3/resource.cfg': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing nagios3-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nagios3-cgi:
 nagios3-cgi depends on nagios3-common (= 3.2.3-1ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package nagios3-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nagios3-cgi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nagios3-core:
 nagios3-core depends on nagios3-common (= 3.2.3-1ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package nagios3-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nagios3-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nagios3:
 nagios3 depends on nagios3-core (= 3.2.3-1ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package nagios3-core is not configured yet.
 nagios3 depends on nagios3-cgi (= 3.2.3-1ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package nagios3-cgi is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nagios3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 nagios3-common
 nagios3-cgi
 nagios3-core
 nagios3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
jason@jason-VirtualBox:/etc$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove /etc/nagios3 directory:

```
rm -rf /etc/nagios3
```

And then you can install it again.

Only notice: if you will remove package including it's config files, you have use a `--purge` option for apt:

```
apt-get --purge remove nagios3-common
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy open synaptic package manager status installed manually you will find there all file give trouble to reinstall nagios3 then command line sudo apt-get install -y nagios3

Comment: He might not be using a GUI.